# Node.js ZeroMQ client does not exchange REQ/REP messages with a C ZeroMQ server

Tags: c, node.js, zeromq

Using the examples provided by the ZeroMQ docs, I cannot get them work with a server written in C and a node.js client.

The examples I use are:

- http://zguide.zeromq.org/js:rrclient
  for Node.js:

---

```
// Hello World client in Node.js
// Connects REQ socket to tcp://localhost:5559
// Sends "Hello" to server, expects "World" back

var zmq       = require('zmq')
  , requester = zmq.socket('req');

requester.connect('tcp://localhost:5560');
var replyNbr = 0;
requester.on('message', function(msg) {
  console.log('got reply', replyNbr, msg.toString());
  replyNbr += 1;
});

for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  requester.send("Hello");
}
```

and

- https://github.com/booksbyus/zguide/blob/master/examples/C/rrworker.c
  for the C server:

---

```
//  Hello World worker
//  Connects REP socket to tcp://localhost:5560
//  Expects "Hello" from client, replies with "World"

#include "zhelpers.h"
#include <unistd.h>

int main (void) 
{
    void *context = zmq_ctx_new ();

    //  Socket to talk to clients
    void *responder = zmq_socket (context, ZMQ_REP);
    //zmq_connect (responder, "tcp://localhost:5560");
    // using bind instead of connect
    zmq_bind (responder, "tcp://localhost:5560");

    while (1) {
        //  Wait for next request from client
        char *string = s_recv (responder);
        printf ("Received request: [%s]\n", string);
        free (string);

        //  Do some 'work'
        sleep (1);

        //  Send reply back to client
        s_send (responder, "World");
    }
    //  We never get here, but clean up anyhow
    zmq_close (responder);
    zmq_ctx_destroy (context);
    return 0;
}
```

I changed the port, so they now match ( 5560 ). However I get no data transmitted. Neither the client nor the server gets any message.

Comment: What return code does your code receive from a call to the zmq_bind() ?

Comment: zmq_bind returns -1 and errno no such device

Answer (score 0):

### Why? Simply they both just remained listening

Where?

```
requester.connect(..)                               // in Node.js copy/paste code
```

resp.

```
zmq_connect ( responder, "tcp://localhost:5560" );  // in C copy/paste code
```

The logic of a ZeroMQ signalling / messaging infrastructure is a bit more complex.

One side of the **`REQ/REP`** has to **`.bind()`** and all the others ***may try to*** **`.connect()`**.

This is valid in principle, applicable to all ZeroMQ Scalable Formal Communication Pattern archetypes, not just to the REQ/REP one.

So, in this use-case,
**either side** -- be it a Node.js or the C -- may start with the **`.bind()`**
and
**the other** one will be able to **try to `.connect()`** to such a `.bind()`-prepared and ready `IP:port#` target.

```
   ..
   int rc = zmq_bind( responder, "tcp://localhost:5560" );
   /*       zmq_bind()
                       returns:
                              * zero if successful.
                              * -1 otherwise
                                   and
                                   sets errno to one of the values
                                              as defined in API.
      */
   ..
```

There are many good practices to follow in ZeroMQ domain. Registering and handling the return codes from the function calls being one such topic in ZeroMQ best practices. [Do not hesitate to **learn faster** and read through many man*years of a Collective-Experience in this **here**.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zeromq?sort=active&pageSize=100)

Comment: Yes i'm aware of this but changing zmq_connect to zmq_bind does not resolve my problem. Since the nodejs exemple used connect on both sides I thought it could be fine doing the same.

Comment: You would be the first source confirming a .connect()-only could work. There must be one .bind(), who makes the ip:port# exposed and visible to others, so as to .connect(). Toy examples are poor in dismantling resources. Code above stops sending REQ-s after some time, but shows Zero-steps for resources used release to make them again free for other use. This un-friendly termination may prevent others from using the IP:PORT# for remarkable time ( incl. during this very the same code re-runs, as these singular resources were not properly released from the code and returned back to the system )

Answer (score 0):

Binding to localhost does not seem to work, so I tried 127.0.0.1 and it works.